# OpenStack Swift proxy-server.conf already had [filter:authtoken] section

Tags: swift, openstack, devstack, keystone

I'm trying to use swift with keystone authentication. I followed this link https://docs.openstack.org/swift/latest/overview_auth.html#keystone-auth to edit my proxy-server.conf but I noticed that at the bottom of the file [filter:authtoken] is already there, while in the comments section I can uncomment a section with the same name of [filter:authtoken], right now the bottom part looks like this:

```
[filter:authtoken]
include_service_catalog = False
cache = swift.cache
delay_auth_decision = 1
memcached_servers = localhost:11211
cafile = /opt/stack/data/ca-bundle.pem
project_domain_name = Default
project_name = service
user_domain_name = Default
password = 1234
username = swift
auth_url = http://10.180.204.223/identity
interface = public
auth_type = password
```

What should I do with it? Should I keep it, modify it according to the link, or should I uncomment the section and add the code according to the link?

Comment: Have you considered the installation guide? For example for Ubuntu: https://docs.openstack.org/swift/latest/install/controller-install-ubuntu.html#install-and-configure-components.

Comment: I installed Swift alongside with Devstack, going to try the guide you provided and will update the progress

Comment: If you use Devstack, the simpler solution is to [add Swift to local.conf](https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/configuration.html#swift). In addition to the instructions, also set SWIFT_HASH to some value. If not, you will be asked for a value when running stack.sh.

Comment: I put ```enable_service s-proxy s-object s-container s-account``` and the hash, and Swift is installed now. However, I wasn't able to access the swift container using boto3, along with my ec2 credential and Swift endpoint, do I need to configure swift middleware further?

Comment: S3 is not enabled by default. Off the cuff, I don't know whether this can be done in local.conf or requires manual configuration.

Comment: I'm trying ```enable_service s3api``` in local.conf, maybe that will work